# Test With Server Example Code Not Working

Tags: scala, playframework

I am not understanding something about this example in [Play 2.7 documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest)

```
class ExampleSpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneServerPerSuite {

  // Override app if you need an Application with other than
  // default parameters.
  override def fakeApplication(): Application = {
    GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .appRoutes(app => {
        case ("GET", "/") => app.injector.instanceOf(classOf[DefaultActionBuilder]) { Ok("ok") }
      }).build()
  }

  "test server logic" in {
    val wsClient = app.injector.instanceOf[WSClient]
    val myPublicAddress = s"localhost:$port"
    val testPaymentGatewayURL = s"http://$myPublicAddress"
    // The test payment gateway requires a callback to this server before it returns a result...
    val callbackURL = s"http://$myPublicAddress/callback"
    // await is from play.api.test.FutureAwaits
    val response = await(wsClient.url(testPaymentGatewayURL).addQueryStringParameters("callbackURL" -> callbackURL).get())

    response.status mustBe OK
  }
}
```

The problem is this code:

```
  .appRoutes(app => {
    case ("GET", "/") => app.injector.instanceOf(classOf[DefaultActionBuilder]) { Ok("ok") }
```

I get message that it expecting Application => PartialFunction[(String, String), Handler]

What is Handler? Is my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is down to lack of type inference I assume.

If you add the required type annotation (i.e. add `: PartialFunction[(String, String), Handler]`) you should be able to compile:

```
  override def fakeApplication(): Application = {
    GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .appRoutes(app => {
        case ("GET", "/") => app.injector.instanceOf(classOf[DefaultActionBuilder]) { x => play.api.mvc.Results.Forbidden }
      }: PartialFunction[(String, String), Handler]
      ).build()
  }
```